# if something <= 0 I want to skip around 30 - 40 lines

Tags: python

I want to skip some lines in Python if something is equal to or less than 0. Here is an example:

```
ye = input()
if ye <= 0:
    #skip lines
else:
   #do nothing
```

So how I will I be able to skip lines? I can do nothing (I now how to), but how will I skip 40 lines? I looked on google and all I saw was Python help which is like a whole story and is barely useful.

To rephrase what I said I want to skip lines (a specific amount of lines (10+ lines)) if the `if` statement is true, else I will just `import time` and do `time.sleep(0.1)`.

Comment: Do you mean skipping lines of code or skipping lines from a read data file?

Comment: skipping lines of code

Answer (score 4):

I had to break myself of this habit back in 1985 when I learned Pascal, having previously known only BASIC. In BASIC, it was common to test for the *opposite* of what you really wanted to know, then use `GOTO` to skip ahead over code you *didn't* want to execute.

But this is a workaround for the fact that 1970s BASICs are not proper structured languages and do not support multi-line `IF` blocks. Pascal is a proper structured language (as is Python), so you don't need a workaround.

In short, instead of this:

```
if ye <= 0, somehow skip ahead 40 lines
    # 40 lines you don't want executed when ye <= 0
```

you should think:

```
if ye > 0:
    # 40 lines you don't want executed when ye <= 0
    # i.e., 40 lines you DO want executed if ye > 0
```

This way, the structure of the `if` statement skips the lines for you; you don't need an explicit command to do so.

The other answers about breaking the 40 lines out into a function are also helpful, but mainly because having 40 lines under an `if` statement can be hard to follow. That approach is not, in itself, a solution to the problem.

Comment: Well put and concise. Excellent Answer!

Answer (score 1):

I would consider rewriting/rethinking your code if you ever need to skip lines in this manner.  It would recommend putting the code you want to skip in a function and calling it only when a certain condition is met. That or you can use more conditionals to your advantage

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as python doesn't support GOTO statements, you're going to have to make your code modular. If you could make the 40 lines of code a function, you could simply not run the function when the value is less than or equal to zero. If you don't want to do this, you could just add an if statement. Right now it looks like you want to skip ~40 lines of code, so you could do:

```
    if ye <= 0:
            skipit = 1      #1 for 'true'#
    else:
            skipit = 0      #0 for 'false'#

    if skipit = 0:
            40linesofcode(ye)
    else:
            #do nothing#
```

You would have to turn your 40 lines of code you want to skip into a function, but it shouldn't be too hard. In the future you should write every aspect of your code as a function; as this makes it far easier to work with it later and make changes/repairs.

Comment: You would need to make the 40 lines of code into a function, and then call it by doing 40linesofcode(ye). Here is a link to functions with python. Have fun! http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/functions.html

Answer (score 1):

Python is a structured language and does not let you arbitrarily jump over lines of code. You will need to move the code you want to skip into a separate function like so:

```
def function():
    # do what you want to skip here!
    pass

ye = input()
if ye > 0:
    function()
else:
    # You can either do nothing or you can
    # do the sleep call you mentioned here.
    pass
```

Instead of thinking of "skipping lines", you should think of not executing that code. Functions are the standard way of creating blocks of code in a structured programming language. A function is just a block of code that can be executed from more than one location.

```
def call_me():
    print("You rang?")

ye = input()
if ye <= 0:
    pass
else:
    call_me()
```

Notice how the above example *does not* invoke the `call_me` function when `ye <= 0`. Thus it is effectively skipping all of those lines of code.

However, when you only need the `else` branch of an `if` condition to do something, typically, it makes more sense to invert the logic. That's why I said to use `if ye > 0`. This states *when* you will run `call_me` instead of stating when you will *not* run `call_me`. It's easier to reason about statements that don't involve double negatives.

Comment: wuld you explain in a easier way?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just encapsulate those 40ish lines on a method? then run it only if condition is true. Like:

```
def those40lines( required parameters...):
    those 40 lines...

ye = input()
if ye > 0:
    those40lines( parameters again...)
```

There's no label/GOTO in python AFAIK

Comment: how do you do it also